# How can I insert php variables in a sql query?

Tags: php, sql, forms, parsing, variables

I've found a lot of answers for this that don't seem to work for me.
When I have apostrophes around the variables $message and $email and $date like

```
    'VALUES ('$message', '$email', '$date')';
```

it tells me

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$message' (T_VARIABLE)

When I remove them, I get something like Could not enter data: Unknown column '$message' in 'field list'. I've tried to insert

```
    $message = mysql_real_escape_string($message);    
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $date = mysql_real_escape_string($date);
```

with " " around the variables like

```
'VALUES ("$message", "$email", "$date")';
```

which gets rid of the error message but now, instead of the input from the html form, i'm getting literally "$message" in my database.

What is it that I'm doing wrong?
My simple objective is just to take an email, a message, and the date, and put it in a database. Please help! Thank you!

Here is the complete code I have:

```
     <?php
if($_POST && isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['essay'])) {


    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = 'password';

    $conn=mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser);
    if(! $conn)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("Ink", $conn);

    date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
    $message = $_POST['essay'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $date = date("y-m-d h:i:sa");


    $sql = 'INSERT INTO inktable '.
            '(writings, email, date) '.
            'VALUES ('$message', '$email', '$date')';

    mysql_select_db('ink');
    $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
    if(! $retval)
    {
        die('Could not enter data: ' .mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: Has anyone ever told you about SQL injections?

Comment: try 
INSERT INTO inktable '.
        '(writings, email, date) '.
        'VALUES ('{$message}', '{$email}', '{$date}')';

and use PDO if you can

Comment: Use `mysqli_` instead of `mysql_` . Also you can use pdo. Mysql is deprecated and not at all recommended

Answer (score 5):

I think you need those little dots:

```
  ('.$message.', '.$email.', '.$date.')';
```

Or:

```
 ("'.$message.'", "'.$email.'", "'.$date.'")';
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, it is better to use the PDO, as the easiest way to minimize problems I think ;) Using prepared statements, you can minimize the risk of SQL injections, as **Biffen** said.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

For example, your code with PDO:

```
<?php

if($_POST && isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['essay'])) {

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'password';
$dbname = 'Ink';

date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");

try {
// Try to connect
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);

// Data 
    $message = $_POST['essay'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $date = date("y-m-d h:i:sa");

// query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO inktable (message,email,date) VALUES (:message,:email,:date)";
    $q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array(':message'=>$message,
                      ':email'=>$email,
                      ':date'=>$date));

// Null connection
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) { // if exception
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

?>
```

Comment: Fix it ;) First code was without check, sorry. P.s.: trouble was actually in this line: `$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);` Pay attention to quotes, @jojo-wang